# Recyclerview not calling onCreate or onBind or the constructor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView is not calling onCreate or onBind or the constructor. No breakpoint hit or logs. What could be the reason? what could be the reason? Anybody how to fix this? here is my code. Adapter :

```
public class MainContentRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainContentRecyclerAdapter.MainContentViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public MainContentRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getSingletonInstance();
    imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();
}

public void setData(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,items.size());
}

@Override
public MainContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.e("Sony","onCreateViewHolder");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);
    MainContentViewHolder holder = new MainContentViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.e("Sony","onBindViewHolder");
    Item currentItem = items.get(position);
    if (currentItem.imageURL != null) {
        imageLoader.get(currentItem.imageURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                Log.e("Sony","onResponseImage");
                holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Sony","onErrorImage");
                holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_product);
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class MainContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView itemImage;


    public MainContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItemPic);   
    }
}
}
```

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardItemHolderRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgItemPic"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/itemImageDimen"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/itemImageDimen"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/productImage"
    android:src="@drawable/default_product"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginWidgetTopMargin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    //Calls volleyLibrary to fetch images using google image search
    getData("Sachin");

    mainListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
    mainListView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    mainListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewListAdapter = new MainContentRecyclerAdapter(this);
    mainListView.setAdapter(recyclerViewListAdapter);
    mainListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: Where you Call recyclerViewListAdapter.setData();??

Comment: its in the getdata function

Comment: If my below answer doesn't wokr then please show getData code

Answer (score 1):

The only issue i can see in your code

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

`items.size(); always return 0` To resolve this  call getData after setting the adapter.

```
   recyclerViewListAdapter = new MainContentRecyclerAdapter(this);     
     mainListView.setAdapter(recyclerViewListAdapter);
     getData("Sachin");
```

Also update your

**setData**

```
public void setData(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

OR

```
public void setData(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;        
    }
```

call from your main activity just after when you called setData

```
mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: this getData method is a call to webservice to fetch images and its working properly

Comment: You mean setData is called inside getData after getting images from server?

Comment: yes, setdata is called in response to the webservice call and the response contains data

Comment: it worked when i removed the
mainListView.setHasFixedSize(true); 
 as suggested by SLIDENERD from youtube
@Ishrat thanks for your time man

Comment: @IshRoid worked for me, i had to make getItemCount() return the dataset size for it to work, otherwise if it always returns zero, it doesn't draw anything,
Thanks